# Are multiple info-bar popups for unregistered users the intended behavior of the site?

Tags: discussion, new-users, user-interface, user-experience, popup

I loaded up Stack Overflow for the first time on a new computer last week, and was surprised to see *three* dismissible info-bar popups on my screen.

[image: Screenshot of a question with three info-bars]

This is 424 rows of pixels (if I counted right), almost **25%** of the 1761 rows of pixels my laptop had to spare after browser chrome took its cut.

Is this the intended experience for new users? It kind of reminds me of my days fixing toolbar-infested IE6 machines, which gives me the heebie jeebies.

Comment: It's our way of being more welcoming. The less of the screen a user can see, the less likely it is that they see anything that they can take offense at.

Comment: This is already being addressed in [Can we show new/anonymous users more Q&A?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314134/289905).

Comment: @DavyM …and it raises the chances that they will leave the site before even reading a single post that could considered offensive.

Comment: *"almost 25% of the 1761"*? How generous, that'd be **55%** of the 768 pixels on my laptops entire screen.

Comment: At least the tool bars aren't covering scroll bars like reddit. x D

Comment: The fact that all three `x` to dismiss the dialogs are different is **really** annoying.

Comment: @DavyM Side bar helps, too.

Comment: I'd have to say if I were a new user I'd actually be almost put off by all that. I'd start to associate it with being one of those sites that just throws popups in my face when I scroll down or try to close a tab and they want me to join their newsletter.

Comment: @luk2302 and the inharmonious left-right margins. And the inconsistent capitalization of the multiple "Sign up"/"Sign Up" buttons.

Comment: The longer you look at the screenshot the more it seems to be a master class in bad UX: different `x` , different wording of the same thing, three banners to begin with, different layout styles, different button themes, different highlights of clickable text, different background colors... What are you guys thinking? This is as ugly as it gets. If I ever experienced something like this I would very quickly leave the site I was currently on.

Comment: @luk2302 That's UI, not UX.

Comment: #BannerOverflow

Comment: I'm missing the banner with a blinking red gif saying that I've won 1 million dollars.

Comment: To be fair, the bottom one was probably something that was required to comply with EU GDPR regulations.

Comment: @DavyM That is pure genius, and going straight to my profile

Comment: GDPR does not require such a banner. It's quite the opposite, GDPR allows you to use neccessary data (i.e. cookies) and requires an explicit opt-in for optional data (like user tracking). Both are not addressed by the banner. So it is more informational (read what our neccessary cookies do). The ToS link is useless for the logged out user as well, because they did not accept any ToS, yet. The privacy policy itself is a GDPR requirement, but it does not require a large banner, but only an easy to find link.

Comment: Without free hand drawn red circles this report is kinda unclear :(

Comment: In my opinion, this is even worse on the home page, where unregistered users are prompted with a huge, undismissable sign-up banner. On my laptop, I therefore don't see any questions at all.

Comment: @kayess There is a red freehand circle around the part that needs to be changed. It's just hard to see because it's outside the image.

Comment: Don't forget about the ad (or white-space) right above the title. And the ad covering most of the right side of the screen. And the one on the left. And the left sidebar that probably won't mean anything to new users. And the concerning amount of vertical space between the end of the question and the start of the first answer. The amount of space taken by the actually important content is shockingly little.

Comment: @kayess [Added red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU8Z2.png).